# How to make or implement self relationship in realm database?

Tags: java, realm

I have a table called User. User have friends.

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email; 
}
```

I am using the User class to add User and its friends to realm. My question is, how to link user to its friends?

Answer (score 1):

I just looked through the realm documentation and found my question answer there.

> It is possible to declare recursive relationships which can be useful when >modelling certain types of data.

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private RealmList<Person> friends;
    // Other fields…
}
```

> Use recursive relationships with care as Realm does not currently have cycle detection and you can easily end in infinite loops.
>
> Setting the value to null for a RealmList field will clear the list. That is, the list will be empty (length zero), but no objects have been deleted. The getter for a RealmList will never return null. The returned object is always a list but the length might be zero.

Comment: Actually that comment is outdated. We do have cycle detection now.